# is sails.io efficient enough to build chat website for some 1000 online user at the same time?

Tags: sails.js

I intend to use sails.io to build a chat website. There will be some 1000 user online at the same time. is sails.io is enough to do that? And is there a way to test performance of chat website? with some normal website i known jmeter but for chat website i know nothing at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will depend mostly of the server you will be using for your service.

Sockets are simply an array of connections. You can have as many as you want (within normal memory usage limits of your server machine).

You can checkout this answer for more information on socket costs [What's the maximum number of rooms socket.io can handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507543/whats-the-maximum-number-of-rooms-socket-io-can-handle)

I am currently sails.io for a chat product with 2000+ simultaneous users using it during business hours. Sails socket.io have been holding it pretty well. Nevertheless I got it prepared for horizontal scaling when I maximum capacity starts to show symptoms.You should too.

Comment: do yo have the github repo of your project? @luiz

Comment: Unfortunately it is a company project and therefore I wont be able to share it. But I would be happy to provide any other help I could. Just contact me.